# USB keyboard is ignoring key presses in some very frustrating pattern

Tags: keyboard, usb-device

I booted my laptop docked to a USB keyboard and external monitor.  I've used it in this setup very recently and it was fine.  Today, the USB keyboard is sometimes ignoring a key press.

It happened a couple of times when I hit Home.  But if I test it specifically, the key works fine.

I thought maybe I was hitting it wrong after adjusting from the smaller laptop keyboard.  But then it clearly dropped a few characters when I was starting to type something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is I have `powertop.service` enabled.  Enabling this means `powertop --autotune` runs at startup and enables most extra power-saving features.  It's very useful to improve the battery life.

Unfortunately this includes usb autosuspend on all (?) usb devices which are connected at the time.  Linux deliberately defaults to *not* enabling autosuspend on input devices, due to reports like this, including [my report at the time](http://osdir.com/ml/linux.power-management.lesswatts.general/2008-05/msg00023.html) on what was most likely the same keyboard.  (Logitech Internet 350).

### Workaround

If you booted with the USB keyboard plugged in, just unplug it and then plug it back in again.  This clears the configuration set by `powertop --autotune`.

A more "correct" solution would be to go through each command recommended by `powertop`, and create a boot script which runs all of them except the USB autosuspend one.